# Any way to get better type inference in vscode?

Tags: typescript

I wrote a component with a click handler, like:

```
onClick={(e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
}}
```

which is clear but, reasonably, tsc complains that that isn't a valid signature for `onClick`, which accepts either `undefined` or `React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLDivElement>`. It's pretty obvious which of those is being passed in. Unfortunately, when I click 'infer parameter type' it gives me

```
e: { stopPropogation: () => void; }
```

which isn't correct and also doesn't compile. My gripe here is even looking at the definition for `onClick`, I don't know the param type - I see that it's `React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLDivElement>`, which maps to `EventHandler<MouseEvent<T>>`, with `EventHandler` being defined as:

```
type EventHandler<E extends SyntheticEvent<any>> = { bivarianceHack(event: E): void }["bivarianceHack"];
```

which provides pretty much 0 information. It's not a giant leap to guess that `MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>` might work, but it also might not, based on whatever the bivarianceHack bit does.

Am I doing something wrong, or is it really this complicated to figure out what my function param type should be and the inference logic really can't do any better?

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with a type you're unsure about, hover over or right click on it to see what type it is. Ideally, you'll be able to then reference that same type name elsewhere. For example, for a React click handler, I can see:

[image]

Hopefully, just copying and pasting what you see there will work. From the above, you could then define a component like:

```
const MyDiv = ({
  onClick
}: {
  onClick: (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) => void;
}) => (
  <div onClick={onClick}>foo</div>
);
```

Comment: Strangely I didn't get that parameter typing from the mouse-over. Any idea if that might be config related...?

Comment: That sounds odd. Are you working in a project that has TypeScript installed in its node_modules and is connected to the .ts or .tsx file you have open? See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript